# Modify Files in SD-card windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, io, sd-card

I wanted to know if there is any way to modify (add or remove) files in SD-card in Windows phone 8

Please don't say there is no way as [Moliplayer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/moliplayer-pro/19ea6d3e-e3d9-401d-b30a-f6471811fe08) does this job.

I mean this 3ed party program can delete music and video files from SD card, and also it has created a .MoliData directory in my SD-card so it can also write there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears as though Moliplayer does this ONLY with photos in the Camera Roll:  "FAST upload from PC to the camera roll of the internal storage and/or SD card" Sorry, but direct write access to the SD card is not allowed.

Comment: Actually, see this thread: http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-apps/251662-moliplayer-pro-now-we-can-save-downloaded-videos-sd-card.html    It appears as though Microsoft granted the dev access to write to the SD card.

Comment: I tried to copy a PDF file using "Fast upload from PC" and it could do that without any problem and I found that PDF file in my SD-card root folder so thats more than images and camera roll!

Comment: You clearly did not read my second comment.